# dead code remover adbout gcc -O and higher

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have written a simple code like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#define CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64

#ifdef CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64
static void A( )
{
    printf("A\n");
}
#else
void A( );
#endif

static void B( )
{
    printf("B\n");
}


static int xx( )
{
#ifdef CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64
  return 1;
#else
  return 0;
#endif
}

int main(void)
{
  if (xx( ))   /* define CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64 */
    A( );
  else
    B( );
}
```

If we don't define the `CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64`, `xx( )` will always return `FALSE`, so functiopn A which is only declared, but not implemented will never be called(dead code).

compile it with gcc -O0

```
/tmp/cctSpgGk.o: In function `main':
1.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But it can be compiled by -O1 or higher.

use GCC V6.1.0

It seems that one of the optimization options in the -O1 option eliminates the dead code, I have seen the optimize doccument about GCC

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

but I can't find it.

So I just want to compile this code under the -O0 option, Is it possible ? Are there some optimization flags help me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. `gcc -c your_file.c`.  It will compile just fine to an object file with an undefined public reference to `A`, which is correct. To get an executable, you'll have to link it with another object file that fulfills the reference. The C Standard _allows_ optimization to remove dead function references, but doesn't _require_ it do so.

Comment: gcc -O1 turns on a lot of optimization flags, I try to use them under -O0,but it dodsn't work. Are there some flags that I can use it to compile my code under -O0. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question how to make this code compile with `-O0` and with defined and undefined `CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64`, but without editing the code and without bothering about clean code, readable code, portable code, correct code or maintainable code? I.e. would you be interested in totally horrible proposals, which to any other question would deserve tons of downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

What's worth noting here is this declares a method *signature*:

```
void A( );
```

Where this declares a method *implementation*:

```
void A( ) { };
```

There is a huge difference between these two.

If you're referencing a function with a call you need to implement it. The compiler will decide if it'll optimize that function call away or not depending on other factors, but it'll need to know what that function *does*, not just how it's called.

Comment: I did it on purpose, It can‘t compiled under -O0, but -O1 and higher can optimize it

Comment: I'm not sure how it can be compiled at all with no implementation. Is your compiler supposed to guess what `A()` does? Maybe if it determines that the one branch won't get excuted it strips out the call and you get lucky, the optimizer ignores a problem that's always existed. This code isn't valid without an implementation of `A()`.

Comment: I use gcc v6.1.0, the compiler will not guess the function, but can find it was dead code.

Comment: If we don't define the CONFIG_TARGET_X86_64, xx( ) will always return FALSE, so functiopn A will never be called(dead code).

Comment: Your code is missing an implementation for `A()`. With no optimization the function call is not pruned, so an implementation *must* be defined. Zero dead code optimization is performed with optimizations disabled. Everything gets compiled and linked no matter how obviously useless that code might be. If you don't want to have to compile it, don't call it in the first place. Wall that off with an `#ifdef` or make `xx` a macro, not a function.

Comment: Which optimization option under -O1 optimize this dead code. I can't find it. can you help me? thanks

Comment: You must understand that this code is not correct, `A()` must be defined if it's *ever* used. It doesn't matter if it's used inside a block of code that can't execute, or in a function that itself is never called. Define it and your problem is fixed. If you don't, stop complaining that the compiler is telling you it needs a definition. The compiler is trying to do its job here and it doesn't have all the information it needs to do it.

Comment: At `-O1` or higher the compiler appears to be collapsing your function which returns a static value into a constant and then understands that the one branch never fires, so it ignores that code. At lower levels it has no such insight and it absolutely, positively, **needs an implementation of `A()`** or it cannot finish linking this code. From that perspective the result of `xx` is unknown, and `A()` might run. It literally has no idea.

Comment: This is a demo code from linux kernel, so I just want to compile it under -O0, there are so many code like this. the cost for an implementation of A like A(){ } is to high, and will also cause another issue. So I try to find a flags to avoid it. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "cost is too high"? It's an empty function. The cost should be really low.

Comment: There are so many codes like this, and use different CONFIG_XXX and Architecture. If I implement it simply, it says "multiple definition'"

Comment: What I think is that,gcc can suggest it's a dead code and remove it.It has a lot of optimization flags. which one do this. can I use it/them under -O0. thanks

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. [Read the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and find out. **Try things** and see what happens. You're the one with some seriously broken code you're trying to get working by depending on a quirk of the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `A` as weak:

```
void A (void) __attribute__ ((weak));
```

Then the linker will ignore the undefined symbol reference, but a call to this function will lead to a crash.